# How to refresh from server based on updated package.xml?

Tags: force.com-ide, package.xml

I am trying to compare metadata from 2 environments (SB and prod) so I have extracted the specific components for SB. Since I already have the package.xml, is it possible to copy the xml into the production project and refresh from server to get the metadata for the specific components (from prod), instead of going through the trouble to manually select and add the components again?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

yes that is correct. you can use same package.xml. The only thing to consider is there might be some component which are not available on PROD, in that case component not found error will occur but if you have identical orgs there is no issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare the metadata in two orgs, try these sweet tools.  Originally built by Tquila, but the company was acquired by Accenture, and they've finally reposted their toolkit here:

http://sftoolkit.co/

The sf org compare tool might help you do this all more quickly:

https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/

Cheers!